# How to run code every time the replicator runs?

Tags: lotus-notes

I need a piece of code to execute code triggered by the replicator everytime the

replicator runs

Is there a way to do this?

Thx

Pitt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Notes client since 8.0 is based on Eclipse. You could schedule tasks with the [Eclipse Jobs API](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html) for repeating tasks.

To run tasks with the replicator, there is an Extension Point you can use:

```
<extension point="com.ibm.notes.client.notesSync">
    <unit class="com.notessensei.demo.RunOnReplication"
     id="com.notessensei.demo.runonreplication"
     image="icons/replicate.gif"
     label="NotesSensei's Demo Replication">
    </unit>
</extension>
```

It creates a new entry in the replicator, which you can drag up and down in the list. It starts with the replication either on schedule or manual and runs concurrently with the replications. I haven't found a way yet to have something run after a replication (to process the new arrivals).

Sample code can be found in a [blog post](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-9ARD24) I wrote a while ago.

Hope that helps!